# Install Gradle 1.6 on Mac OS

Tags: macos, gradle, homebrew

Is there any way to get Gradle v1.x on Mac OS El Capitan v10.11 ?

I tried running

```
brew search gradle
```

but only versions displayed were 2.x. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you want to run an old version of Gradle?

Answer (score 2):

In the official gradle downloads page it is possible to get binaries from previoius releases:
http://gradle.org/gradle-download/

Look at the bottom-right side of the page, choose the 1.6 version and install the binaries.